# Sending Continuous Post Requests to Server

Tags: python, flask, file-upload

I am facing a problem when sending continuous post request to server. The program sends encoded data of an image it was working fine on localhost but getting error when hosted on server. Code from a Client Side

```
def send_img(url, my_img):
print(requests.post(url,files=my_img))


def post_img(img_encoded):
print("Sending the  frame....")
my_img = {'image': img_encoded.tobytes()}
thr = Thread(target=send_img, args=[url, my_img])
thr.start()
return 1
```

The Error occur is:

**urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host', None, 10054, None))**

Comment: judging of the error we'll have to see the rest of your code since the error probably isnt in how you send the image but more likely in how you mantain a connection to the server

Comment: My whole client side code is about taking a getting the images from the directory and then sends the encode image to the URL, and the server side API is accepting the encoded image and then save it to a directory. I did nothing to maintain a connection. So how do I maintain a connection and send continuous requests to server.?

Comment: How are you establishing a connection/ what modules are you using? Cause maybe, instead of mantaining a connection, you could just reconnect every time you want to send something, although it might be slower...

Comment: Yes ,my program is reconnecting every time for a every single frame. Instead of making a requests individually. What is the solution of my problem? I also looked into **socket** but not used yet , I also used **ThreadPoolExecutor** to maintain a session. @Canbach Thank You for reaching out.